# metamethods shadowing problems with luaL_ref key

Tags: lua

I have an empty table, whose __newindex and __index metamethods are implemented from the C side. The table is going to be used as an array (t[1]=3, print(t[2])...), with C catching all the accesses.

Now, I want to use luaL_ref to add a reference of another object into this table, just to prevent the second from being thrown away by gc. But I think that the returned reference could shadow the "virtual" indexes that I'm going to use with this table:

For example, I expect t[1]=3 to call the __newindex, but if lauL_ref returned 1 then my table would really have a element at '1', then __newindex wouldn't be called anymore.

I know that luaL_ref is guaranteed to return a key not already used in the table, but since the table is empty (so that my metamethods are always called), I think it actually can return low values, which I'm likely to use.

Are there flaws in this reasoning? If not, how can I workaround this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise not using `luaL_ref` at all. At least, not on the empty table you're putting your metatable on. Maybe you should reference it in the metatable itself, or something other internal table that you store in the registry.

Comment: you don't explain why I shouldn't use luaL_ref at all. Anyway, you and another guy on #lua proposed the same thing about metatables, so I guess that that will be my final approach.

Comment: @LorenzoPistone: You yourself stated the problem with using `luaL_ref`: that it takes up entries in the table and screws up metatable accessing. The table must remain *empty* for the metamethods to work. Therefore, you have to use a different table to hook these references to. This is standard procedure in Lua.